# Unable to select empty or 0 row table in Oracle 12c using Toad

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

```
Oracle version 12.1.0.2.0.
Toad version 12.1.0.22
```

I have a `Table_A` with 2 columns (A NUMBER, B NUMBER). `Table_A` is a new object created for a datafix. No application live objects are referring this.

Due to logic issue, an insert statement initiated a transaction to insert billions of record into the table_A. I found it mid way, killed the Oracle session with help of DBAs. Now the session is killed and I do not see them using session browser in Toad. It took almost 4 hours for the killed session to be removed from session browser. The killed session was available in session browser for the 4 hours with Status as Killed. I believe it must be rolling back the data.

Current Problem: 
If I select (without hint) `Table_A` from my Oracle user account I'm either getting below ora error or the select runs forever (it kept running for more than 30 minutes, so I stopped the execution)

> ORA-02395: exceeded call limit on IO usage

If I select with hint, it returns 0 rows.

```
Select /*+parallel(4)*/ *
from table_A;
```

Question:

Whether Killed session have any issues and running some IO in background ?  I have no clue why the select statement (without hint) is running longer to return 0 rows. As this happened in prod system, I'm worried if any background process would cause any issue in coming days.

Apologies, I do not have DBA privileges to check locks or background running processed. If I missed to provide any additional info, please let me know. Thank you in advance for your time in responding back.

AS this happened in Production system, I do not have access to much of oracle v$ or metadata tables. I tried using session browser to find locks, background process but none helped

```
select *
from table_A;
```

I expect it to return 0 rows without a delay.

Comment: As far as I understood, TABLE_A is currently empty. Is it? If so, nonetheless selecting from it takes too much time. See if **truncate** helps. If that *huge* insert raised high water mark, truncate will *drop* it and - hopefully - help your select run faster. Won't cost much as the table is empty anyway, truncate shouldn't do any harm.

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot. This gave me an idea of why it is running longer now. I will try to truncate the table and retry the select and update here. As this is prod system, I cannot immediately run DDL statement but will soon post the result.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!